# I can't get JSON to display the data on Chart.js

Tags: php, json, mysqli, chart.js

I want to be able to display 2 different json data on 1 bar chart in chart.js. However, my javascript file doesn't recognized the array from Json. The outline of the chart displayed but the labels are undefined.

**Cendex1.php**

```
// suppress error notices
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);




require 'connect.php';




$query="SELECT * FROM employed";
if($result = mysqli_query($db, $query)){


 /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         $dataem[]=array($row[0],$row[1], $row[2]);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}









$output = json_encode($dataem);
echo $output;


?>
```

**cendex2.php**

> `/* fetch associative array */
> while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
>      $dataun[]=array($row[0],$row[1], $row[2]);
> }
> mysqli_free_result($result); }
>
>
>  $output = json_encode($dataun); echo $output;`
>
>   
>   ?>

**Cendis1.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Employment Rate</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Employed</p>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/graph1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chartjs/Chart.js"></script>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

**Graph1.js**

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
>   var ageData = new Array();
>   var emData = new Array();
>   var unData = new Array();
>
>   $.getJSON("cendex1.php", function(data){
>       var em = data;
>       $.each( em, function( i, val ) {
>               ageData.push(val.age);
>               emData.push(val.age);
>       });
>       console.log(emData);
>       getun(ageData, emData);
>   });
>
>   function getun(){
>       $.getJSON("cendex2.php", function(data){
>           var un = data;
>           $.each( un, function( i, val ) {
>               unData.push(val.un);
>           });
>           console.log(unData);
>           createChart();
>       });
>   }
>
>   function createChart() {
>
>       var data = {
>       labels: ageData,
>           datasets: [
>               {
>                   label: "My First dataset",
>                   fillColor: "rgba(46, 138, 83, 1)",
>                   strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
>                   pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
>                   pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
>                   pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
>                   pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
>                   data: emData
>               },
>               {
>                   label: "My Second dataset",
>                   fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
>                   strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
>                   pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
>                   pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
>                   pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
>                   pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
>                   data: unData
>               }
>           ]
>       };
>
>       var options = {
>           responsive: true,
>           maintainAspectRatio: true,
>           scaleFontColor: "#000",
>           datasetStrokeWidth: 5
>       };
>
>       var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
>       var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);
>   }
>
> });
> ```